# Two jars are shuffled.

Tags: probability

One jar contains 2 white balls and 1 black ball. Another jar contains 2 black balls and 1 white ball. The jars are shuffled. A ball is withdrawn which turns out to be a white ball. What are the chances of withdrawing a white ball?

Let $W$ be the event that the ball withdrawn is white. Let $J_1$ be the event that the first white withdrawn was from jar 1.

$$P(W) = P(W|J_1)P(J_1) + P(W|J_2)P(J_2) $$
$$ P(W|J_1)=\frac{1}{2}, P(J_1) = \frac{2}{3}  $$
$$ P(W|J_2)=0, P(J_2) = \frac{1}{2}  $$
so $P(W) = 1/3.$

The solutions say the following

> if we pick the other jar the chances are $$\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3} =  \frac{4}{9}$$

Let $J_1$ be the event that the first white withdrawn was from **jar 2.**

$$P(W) = P(W|J_1)P(J_1) + P(W|J_2)P(J_2) $$
$$ P(W|J_1)=\frac{2}{3}, P(J_1) = \frac{1}{3}  $$
$$ P(W|J_2)=\frac{1}{3}, P(J_2) = \frac{2}{3} $$

Is this what is meant? Is my intuition correct?

Comment: "What are the chances of withdrawing a white ball ?" First or second ? If second, from which jar ? The question doesn't seem clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your notation is confusing because you're using $W$ to denote both 1st and 2nd white withdrawals. Let's call them $W_1$ and $W_2$. Another confusing thing is that we have 2 states of jars - when they are full ($J_1$ and $J_2$) and after we drew from them (smaller $j_1$ and $j_2$).

So the 1st part of the problem requires us to calculate the probability of drawing from either of jars (e.g. $P(J_1|W_1)$) multiplied by probabilities that 2nd withdrawal will be white (e.g. $P(W_2|j_1)$):

$$P(W_2) = P(J_1|W_1) P(W_2|j_1) + P(J_2|W_1)P(j_2) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}0$$

You seem (again it's confusing because you wrote $P(J_2)$ instead of $P(J_2|W_1)$) to be saying that $P(J_2|W_1) = \frac{1}{2}$, while in fact you end up with $P(J_2|W_1) = \frac{P(W_1|J_2)P(J_2)}{P(W_1)} = \frac{1}{3}$. But this doesn't change your answer because eventually this was multiplied by $P(j_2)=0$.

The 2nd part of the task says that 2nd withdrawal ($W_2$) should happen from *another* jar, therefore it's:

$$
P(W_2) = P(J_1|W_1)P(W|J_2) + P(J_2|W_1)P(W|J_1) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{9}
$$

Where $W$ is the probability of drawing while ball from a full jar.

Comment: I think OP consistently uses $W$ to represent only the second draw, but both the original problem statement and the solution are worded ambiguously, both in the story of what is happening and in the assignment of variables. You can also fault the solution for using $P(J_1)$ to represent $P(J_1\mid W_1),$ but then you should write $P(W_2\mid W_1)$ rather than $P(W_2).$

Comment: Hm.. But $W_2$ implies there was $W_1$, isn't $P(W_2 | W_1)$ excessive?

Comment: I would interpret $W_2$ to mean that the second ball drawn is white, regardless of what happened before. If you start using $W_1$ and $W_2$ to represent the first and second white balls drawn in a sequence of draws, it quickly becomes unworkable. But using your definition, surely $P(W_2\mid W_1^C) = 0,$ and $P(W_2) < P(W_2\mid W_1),$ that is, drawing a white ball the first time considerably improves the chance that you'll draw a second white ball.